# logout - keep or delete cookies

Tags: cookies, user-experience

If on login page user specifies 'remember me for a week', which means he gets a cookie for 1 week, what is an appropriate action on logout? logout and delete his cookie with 1 week preference, or just redirect him somewhere and keep the same cookie as he asked before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is a meaningful semantic of "remember me" if "logout" cannot undo it? Usually "remember me" means that the user comes back *without* needing to authenticate again, so an explicit "logout" should definitely destroy the "remembered" session and require authentication again.

Answer (score 0):

I think "Remember me" should not persist the cookie if its logged off. It must only remembers in case of closing and starting browser sessions.